# How can i extracted the information after /

Tags: php

i have this information `$estimate =123456/5` and i want keep the all information after / on other variable all this in function

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are these numbers or is it a string?

Comment: Must be string, otherwise `$estimate` is a float 24691,2

Comment: @Rizier123 it's Number No String

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use php explode

```
 $estimate ='123456/5';
 print_r (explode("/",$estimate));
 $arr=explode("/",$estimate);
 echo $arr[1];
```

Comment: [Your code failed.](https://eval.in/452045) \[EDIT\]:[Still fails](https://eval.in/452047). You're missing a semicolon at first line but that isn't the main problem, `$estimate` isn't a string, can't be exploded.

Comment: pls check again [https://eval.in/452051] @AlanMachado

Comment: Kudos! Pity that OP's question is major unclear. **PS:** [even shorter one](https://eval.in/452057)

Comment: Answering bad questions just encourages more bad questions.

Comment: @Rizier123 yes you are right :(